# SQL Getting all Related Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been trying to figure out (very slowly) over the last two weeks how to come up with a better way to query for all related rows to an ID. My company is in a situation were a brand keeps getting renamed and we don't have the option of modifying previous records (in a few other tables) that point to the brand that got replaced.

I've made a small, small version of my table to help invite people to check:

```
CREATE TABLE #GrwHist
(
    ID INT
    , Acronym VARCHAR(50)
    , New_ID INT
)

INSERT INTO #GrwHist VALUES(1,'ABC',33)
INSERT INTO #GrwHist VALUES(21,'GST',NULL)
INSERT INTO #GrwHist VALUES(33,'MnY',48)
INSERT INTO #GrwHist VALUES(37,'FWR',89)
INSERT INTO #GrwHist VALUES(48,'DMZ',89)
INSERT INTO #GrwHist VALUES(89,'PLT',106)
INSERT INTO #GrwHist VALUES(106,'TnI',NULL)
INSERT INTO #GrwHist VALUES(120,'YIZ',143)
INSERT INTO #GrwHist VALUES(143,'INZ',NULL)

SELECT * FROM #GrwHist
/*
ID  Acronym New_ID
--- ------- ------- 
1   ABC     33
21  GST     NULL
33  MnY     48
37  FWR     89
48  DMZ     89
89  PLT     106
106 TnI     NULL
120 YIZ     143
143 INZ     NULL
*/

DECLARE @ID INT
SET @ID = 106

SELECT * FROM #GrwHist WHERE ID = @ID
UNION
SELECT * FROM #GrwHist WHERE New_ID in (@ID)
UNION
SELECT * FROM #GrwHist WHERE New_ID in (SELECT ID FROM #GrwHist WHERE New_ID in (@ID))
UNION
SELECT * FROM #GrwHist WHERE New_ID in (
    SELECT ID FROM #GrwHist WHERE New_ID in (SELECT ID FROM #GrwHist WHERE New_ID in (@ID))
)
UNION
SELECT * FROM #GrwHist WHERE New_ID in (
    SELECT ID FROM #GrwHist WHERE New_ID in (SELECT ID FROM #GrwHist WHERE New_ID in (SELECT ID FROM #GrwHist WHERE New_ID in (@ID)))
)
UNION
SELECT * FROM #GrwHist WHERE New_ID in (
    SELECT ID FROM #GrwHist WHERE New_ID in (SELECT ID FROM #GrwHist WHERE New_ID in (SELECT ID FROM #GrwHist WHERE New_ID in (SELECT ID FROM #GrwHist WHERE New_ID in (@ID))))
) --And it grows and grows...
GO
DROP TABLE #GrwHist
```

The last query is basically for:

```
--If I need to get all IDs related to a given ID I will get the following results:
@ID = 106 --> 106, 89, 48, 37, 33, 1
@ID = 143 --> 143, 120
@ID = 21 --> 21
```

The problem with this query is that there may be more than 7-8 levels, and I was wondering if I can do this dynamically, so that I won't worry if my code needs to be changed each time there is another row with a relation is added. Say if a new row is added to replace the one with ID 106, I'll have to keep adding.

Thank you in advance for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE to get the matches:

```
with cte as (
      select id, acronym, null as newid, id as baseid, 1 as lev,
             cast(id as varchar(max)) as ids
      from #GrwHist h
      where newid is null
      union all
      select h.id, h.acronym, h.newid, cte.baseid, cte.lev + 1
             cte.ids + ',' + cast(h.id as varchar(max)) as ids
      from cte join
           #GrwHist h
           on h.new_id = cte.id
     )
select baseid, ids
from (select cte.*, max(lev) over (partition by baseid) as maxlev
      from cte
     ) cte
where maxlev = lev;
```

EDIT:

If there are duplicates, you can get each id using:

```
select baseid, id
from cte
order by baseid;
```

Getting values on one row is a bit more complicated.

Comment: This is.. AMAZING.. It looks like it was simple for you but I can't begin to understand. However, it is working for all! Just that row with ID 37 wasn't included. Row with ID 37 is a case where two brands were merged. Is there a way to add it?

Comment: @Busy . . . If they are not a simple chain, then the logic is a bit more complicated.

Comment: Now I wish I asked here two weeks ago. I was trying so hard to figure it out on my own because I was so afraid someone might just tell me I didn't try and just close my thread. So I kept trying dynamic SQL etc for two weeks with no sustainable progress. THANK YOU SO MUCH; answer accepted! You are a godsend, @GordonLinoff